# I clear an arraylist in my main, but when I addall from another class, the original data reappears before the new data is added

Tags: android, arraylist

I clear an arraylist in my main (sizecheck says 0), but when I addall from my class again the original data reappears before the new data, size check confirms this. Is there any way around this?

To clarify: I keep clearing, size confirmed by log cmd that arraylist size is 0, and re-adding new data just adds to the total. clear 50-->0, then add 50 = 100, clear 100-->0 and add 50 again and it's 150, etc.

Help me kill this zombie data!

Below is abridged:

```
ArrayList<Integer> imagearray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
....onCreate....
imagearray.clear(); // confirmed this makes arraylist size = 0
imagearray.addAll(animalclass.getpics(songtolearn)); 
// this last line is dragging all the cleared data back and adds the new data too
```

which drags the data from:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getpics(int songnumber) {

switch (songnumber) { 
case 1:
  animalpics.add(1);
  animalpics.add(1);
break;
return animalpics;
```

Comment: Please post some code. Where does your data keep reappearing? In the arraylist itself? In a ListView? Somewhere else?

Comment: It reappears in the arraylist, the arraylist size is larger than expected because of this data.

Comment: The data is coming from *somewhere*, but without more context, I don't see how anybody could help.

Comment: I suspect that getpics is returning more and more data each time, probably because animalpics is an instance var rather than a local.

Comment: Hot licks you are correct. Please post this comment as a full answer if you want the points! In the class animals I needed to remove the ArrayList<Integer> animalpics = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and place it withing the getpics command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class animals I needed to remove the ArrayList animalpics = new ArrayList(); from where i declare variables and place it within the local getpics command.